# Down down menu not working when converted from HTML to aspx page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I converted this HTML template into .aspx by opening it in Adobe dreamweaver and saving as aspx. It was working fine in HTML version but not working on this page.
http://www.talismanmovers.ca/test.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript"> src="http://gtasites.com/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> src="http://gtasites.com/js/scripts.js"></script>
```

These are very clear syntactical errors. I would suggest not relying completely on some tool to draw out all the code for you. This problem was quite obvious from the error it was throwing in the console.